# How to set background invisible in react on one component on top of another

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, frontend

In React on a button click I make a small component (compSmall) visible on top of another big component (compBig). using css properties on compSmall such as

```
 position: absolute;
 width: 300px;
 height: 150px;
 margin-left: 40%;
 margin-top: 200px;
 border: 1px solid #0083a5;
 z-index: 100;
```

But when compSmall is visible on top of compBig, background (means content of compBig) still visible . But I want content of compBig is to be not visible clear or blur when compSmall is visible.

How to achieve this.
PS:
I can only apply properties on compSmall, not on CompBig. Since CompBig is the whole application component except compSmall.

Comment: Can you add codesandbox reproducing your issue?

Comment: You could wrap the small component in a div that is 100% in width and height, use display flex to center align its content and you are done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about make compSmall with the same size of compBig, so you will not see the compBig and inside the compSmall you can create another component or just a div with those css properties.

JSX

```
<CompBig>
 <CompSmall className="compSmall">
  <div className="content"></div>
 </CompSmall>
</CompBig>
```

CSS

```
.content {
 position: absolute;
 width: 300px;
 height: 150px;
 margin-left: 40%;
 margin-top: 200px;
 border: 1px solid #0083a5;
 z-index: 100;
}

.compSmall {
   /* Add the blur effect */
  filter: blur(8px);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%
}
```